# What are the parameters for using WinMerge in Subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, winmerge

For using WinMerge in Subclipse, What are the parameters in `Preferences > Team > SVN > Diff/Merge`?

Is this correct?

```
/dl "Base" /dr "Mine" "${base}" "${mine}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclipse only supports using an external tool for resolving conflicts which generally requires a tool that can do a 3-way diff.  I do not see where WinMerge supports this from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks like I have to look for other tools then.

Comment: Other tool for what exactly?  The Eclipse compare and merge tool is pretty nice IMO.  Beyond Compare is supposed to be a good tool and it integrates into core Eclipse so that it can replace the default compare mechanism.

Comment: I seem to find the diff for WinMerge better than subclipse's.

Comment: FWIW, the compare/merge UI is part of Eclipse.  Subclipse just gives it the files to diff.  Have you looked at the Quick Diff feature which lets you see the diff in the file you are editing? http://blog.mxunit.org/2009/04/timesavers-eclipse-quick-diff.html

Comment: FWIW I find eclipse's diffing algorithm pretty mediocre... IMO.